# Grid panel doesnot render store in ext js 6.0.0

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I am studying book 'Mastering Ext Js', I came across problem on Grid Panel doesnot load the data from store, I have debug Json format server came well, i dont know what the issue since there is no error in console.

Here is my model class

```
Ext.define("pg.model.security.User", {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
idProperty: 'userName',
fields: [
    {
        name: 'userName'
    }, {
        name: 'roleId'
    }, {
        name: 'fullName'
    }, {
        name: 'emailId'
    }, {
        name: 'mobileNumber'
    }, {
        name: 'landLineNumber'
    }, {
        name: 'picture'
    }
]
});
```

here is store class

```
Ext.define('pg.store.security.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: [
    'pg.model.security.User' // #1
],
storeId:'userStore',    
model: 'pg.model.security.User', // #2
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/parkgarau-ws/ws/park/userlist',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data'
    }
}
});
```

From url, i will be successfully retrieving JSON format

*{"code":200,"message":"Success","data":"[{\"userName\":\"admin\",\"roleId\":\"SYS_ADMIN\",\"fullName\":\"Bibek Shakya\",\"emailId\":\"bibek@drose.com.np\",\"mobileNumber\":\"9843598726\",\"landLineNumber\":\"014323565\",\"picture\":\"index.jpg\"}]"}*

here is my view class extend Grid Panel

```
Ext.define('pg.view.security.UsersList', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.userslist',
frame: true,
store: Ext.create('pg.store.security.Users'), // #1
columns: [
    {
        width: 150,
        dataIndex: 'userName',
        text: 'Username'
    },
    {
        width: 200,
        dataIndex: 'fullName',
        flex: 1,
        text: 'Name'
    }, {
        width: 250,
        dataIndex: 'emailId',
        text: 'Email'
    }
]
 });
```

This is my controller class

```
Ext.define('pg.controller.security.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
views: [
    'security.Users' // #1
],
init: function (application) {
    this.control({
        "userslist": {// #2
            render: this.onRender
        }
    });
},
onRender: function (component, options) { // #3
    this.getStore('userStore').load();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out what was the problem, Problem was on json format, 
if the format contain'/' it is not going to worked out

```
{
 "code":200,
 "message":"Success",
 "data":"[{\"userName\":\"admin\",\"roleId\":\"SYS_ADMIN\",\"fullName\":\"Bibek Shakya\",\"emailId\":\"bibek@drose.com.np\",\"mobileNumber\":\"9843598726\",\"landLineNumber\":\"014323565\",\"picture\":\"index.jpg\"}]"}
```

but with the clear json format it worked well

```
[{"userName":"admin","roleId":"SYS_ADMIN","fullName":"Bibek Shakya","emailId":"bibek@drose.com.np","mobileNumber":"9843598726","landLineNumber":"014323565","picture":"index.jpg"}]
```

Comment: It's not because of `\"`. It's because you were enclosed an array `[....]` in double quotes.

Comment: @Thevs i dont understand, it is the format of server, Response(code,msg,data),

Comment: @B'bekShakya Please show the server-side code for JSON generation. There's something wrong with it.

Comment: @Alexander First one

Comment: @B'bekShakya Please use a JSON validator to check your JSON before use.